# Mininet error in Ubuntu 16.04 while setting bandwidth

Tags: ubuntu, mininet, openvswitch

`sudo mn --link tc,bw=10,delay=10m` gives the following

```
$ sudo mn --link tc,bw=10
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 
*** Adding switches:
s1 
*** Adding links:
(10.00Mbit) *** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
(10.00Mbit) *** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
(h1, s1) (10.00Mbit) *** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
(10.00Mbit) *** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
(h2, s1) 
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 
*** Starting controller
c0 
*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...(10.00Mbit) (10.00Mbit) 
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> exit
*** Stopping 1 controllers
c0 
*** Stopping 2 links
..
*** Stopping 1 switches
s1 
*** Stopping 2 hosts
h1 h2 
*** Done
completed in 199.858 seconds
```

Reproducible in Ubuntu 16 but not in Ubuntu 14

No error if `bw`, `delay` is not set. Can any one help please?

Answer (score 0):

[Issue #629](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/issues/629)  at the repository suggests to install from source and not from Ubuntu repo.

```
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/mininet/mininet
cd mininet
sudo make install
```